# Custom Fields/Meta Boxes - Only Display If Value is Present

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I am using the [Custom Metaboxes and Fields](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress) for WordPress add-on to create custom fields for custom post types. However, I need a way to display content only if a value exists for a specific custom field.

Currently, I am using this code:

```
<?php 
$url = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'snippet-reference-URL', true); 
    if ($url) {
    echo "<p><a href='$url'>Reference URL</a></p>";
} ?>
```

However, this displays content if the field is present (which in this case, is always). I need code that will only display content if a specific field has a value.

Comment: Could you clarify the distinction between the field "having a value" and a being "present"?

Comment: A custom field will always be present, however, sometimes it will not have a value. For example, I have a custom field for "Bio Image", however, not all posts will have a "Bio Image". Therefor, the custom field will be "present" but have "no value".

Comment: A better example would be above. While the "snippet-reference-URL" field will always be present, it will not always have a value. I need to create an IF STATEMENT that will only display content if the custom field has a value (any value).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check this example given on [codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta#show_the_first_value_of_the_specified_key_inside_a_loop)

```
<?php 
$key_1_value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'key_1', true );
// check if the custom field has a value
if( ! empty( $key_1_value ) ) {
echo $key_1_value;
} 
?>
```